# Proving exactness not at the connecting hom in a Snake Lemma subproblem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, exact-sequence, diagram-chasing

Here's a picture of the Snake Lemma from nLab:

[image: Snake Lemma picture from nLab]

I'm having trouble showing exactness at $\ker g$ and haven't even got to the connecting hom yet.  So let's focus on $\ker g$.  Let $q : A' \to B'$ be the hom such that $\text{im} \ q = \ker p$.  Then for one direction, namely $\text{im} \ \overline{q} \subset \ker \overline{p}$ we have $x = \overline{q}(x') = q(x)$ since $\overline{q}$ is simply a restriction of $q$.  But $p \circ q (x) = 0$ by assumption of exactness of rows of the central diagram.   Thus $\overline{p} \circ \overline{q} (x) = 0$ since $\overline{q}, \overline{p}$ are simply restrictions of $q, p$.  But that means precisely that $\text{im} \ q \subset \ker p$.

I'm having trouble showing the other direction, $\ker \overline{p} \subset \text{im} \ \overline{q}$.  If  $\overline{p}(x) = 0$, then $p(x) = 0 \implies x = q(x')$ for some $x' \in A'$.  But how do I show then that $x' \in \ker f$ necessarily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use commutativity.

If $x\in \ker g$ with $p(x)=0$, then as you've noted, there is $x'\in A'$ with 
$q(x')=x$.

Then $$0=g(x)=gq(x')=if(x'),$$
but by exactness of the second row, $i$ is injective, so $f(x')=0$. Therefore $x'\in \ker f$, as desired.

Comment: This is great! Thank you :)  I forgot to say $x \in \ker g$, but you lit the way.